# Can I use a heat gun or hair dryer to remove plastic from my steel door

Tags: plastic

I failed to remove the plastic from my steel door and now I am unable to peel it off. Can I use a heat gun or hair dryer to remove it, or is there a better way? I have tried several different things, but none seem to work.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Some more information, or even better a picture, would help us help you.

Comment: I think OP means the product came wrapped in plastic, or with stickers, and "to reduce initial wear" he left the plastic on, and now the sun's UV has cooked the adhesive to where it is no longer cooperative.

Comment: Many metal surfaces come covered with a thin sheet of clear plastic or white plastic to keep it from getting scratched, I would use googone or goof off , I really like Dr-solve-it contractors solvent with quick release echo friendly I think I purchased at home depot but liked it so much I bought a gallon and that was years ago still have some left.

Comment: can you please post a photo of what you're facing?

Answer (score 2):

You do not mention what kind of plastic this is or how it is adhered to the door - but since you said peel it off...

Don't use a heat gun - it will melt the plastic.

If the plastic is glued on to the door

Use something like this to dissolve the glue :
[image: Goo Gone]

Comment: I believe he's talking about the compliance stickers that are plastered all over a new residential entry door.

Comment: Most stickers and labels will come off with some paint thinner (mineral spirits and/or turpentine) and persistent scrubbing.